# split magento sites into separate magento instances

Tags: php, magento

I've been tasked with splitting up a Magento store with many sites into many independent installations. Is there any easy way to accomplish this task? I was thinking of just copying the entire store and database, and then deleting the other stores from the duplicate, and continue this way until the task is done, and then delete all the sites off of the main store. Are there any inherent problems with this approach, or anything that I should be aware of before embarking?

Comment: this is the correct way, make a shell script for that and let it run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like the right approach to me, just make sure that you take backups (complete and verified backups **that you have done test restores of**) and try the first couple of sites in your development environment.  You'll need to make sure that you get the right store codes in the Manage Stores section, but that's fairly straight forward.

Out of interest, why are they being split?  I can't imagine too many good technical reasons for the split?

Comment: performance issues most probably :) indexes running out of time or running 8 hours straight

Comment: Yes, performance. I'm not sure that it will actually result in a gain, they will still all be on the same server. I guess we will see, I tried to mention the possibility that it may not be faster, but that didn't go over so well.

Comment: From my experience, if they are still on the same server, you will almost definitely find that it **slows** the server.  Much better to have a single install that it optimized.  Get your MySQL settings tweaked, install APC, use a CDN, turn off unnecessary Module modules, etc.  All much better options than duplicating the stack. Contact me if you want more information.